# PHP Syntax Error on line 15

Tags: php, wordpress

I am receiving the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' on line 15

```
<?php 
    if ( is_single() && $post->post_parent ) {
        echo '<script src="<?php bloginfo'template_directory'); ?>/_/js/ZeroClipboard.min.js"></script>';
        echo '<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_/js/functions.js"></script>';
    }
?>
```

Line 15: `echo '<script src="<?php bloginfo'template_directory'); ?>/_/js/ZeroClipboard.min.js"></script>';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing opening bracket, moreover you are using `<?php ?>` in your echo statement which is invalid

```
 bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>
```

Correct syntax

```
<?php 
    if ( is_single() && $post->post_parent ) {
?>
       <script src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_/js/ZeroClipboard.min.js"></script>
       <script src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_/js/functions.js"></script>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ha! Just figured that out as soon as I posted this. I appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: From reading all the answers which one actually renders faster?

Comment: Basically you shouldn't echo out so much of HTML using PHP

Comment: I believe you forgot to delete the semicolons

Comment: @ChristopherBurton oops, thnx ;)

Answer (score 1):

you are echo the text and also include php tag inside the echo text it should be

```
<?php 
if ( is_single() && $post->post_parent ) { ?>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_/js/ZeroClipboard.min.js">  </script>;
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_/js/functions.js"></script>;
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: you cannot use `<?php ?>` inside `<?php ?>`

Comment: @Mr.Alien yes, i have over the php tag after the if braces :)

Answer (score 1):

you missed an opening bracket after bloginfo, plus you can't open a new php tag within a php script, therefor this line should work.

```
echo '<script src="'.bloginfo('template_directory') .'/_/js/ZeroClipboard.min.js"></script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    if ( is_single() && $post->post_parent ) {
        echo '<script src="'.bloginfo('template_directory').
'/_/js/ZeroClipboard.min.js"></script><script src="'. bloginfo('template_directory').
'/_/js/functions.js"></script>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ( is_single() && $post->post_parent ) {
        echo '<script src='.bloginfo("template_directory").'/_/js/ZeroClipboard.min.js"></script>';
        echo '<script src='.bloginfo("template_directory").'/_/js/functions.js"></script>';
}
```